# Summing a column, filtered based on another column in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
+------+---------+
| Time | Include |
+------+---------+
| 0:30 | No      |
| 1:00 | Yes     |
| 0:30 | Yes     |
| 0:30 | No      |
| 0:30 | Yes     |
+------+---------+
```

I would like to add up the time where the column to the right is "Yes".

I am using the following to add up all time (3:00):

```
=SUM(A1:A5)
```

and I've tried the following to add up the time (2:00) where the adjacent column is Yes, but Google reports "#ERROR!":

```
=SUM(FILTER(A1:A5;B1:B5="Yes"))
```

Comment: If you'd searched here on [webapps.se], then you would've found a few examples on how to do a summation. Another way of doing it is by using the `SUMIF` formula: `=SUMIF(B2:B6;"Yes";A2:A6)`

Comment: The reason to why you need a comma in stead of a semicolon, has to do with the time-zone your in. Europe uses a comma as where USA uses a semicolon.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: Whether you can use a comma or semicolon is not necessarily related to the timezone, but with the locale/_language_ settings. Specifically whether the comma is being used as a decimal separator. If it is then you can't use a comma to also separate function arguments. In English we generally use a period as a decimal separator, so we can use either.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Just realised [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) should be comma separated:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A1:A5,B1:B5="Yes"))
```

Comment: Note that whether you need to use a comma or semicolon to separate function arguments is dependent on your language settings.

Comment: Thanks! Another useful one is: `=sum(Filter(A2:A, B2:B > EOMonth(now(), -1)))`, which sums all of the values for the current month, where `A2:A` contains the values, and `B2:B` contains the associated date.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: comma or semicolon usage should be specified in the accepted answer

Comment: while this answer and the one below perfectly answers the question, I wonder if there is a solution using QUERY, as it would be more "tweakable"

Comment: Currently it works only with semicolon instead of comma.

Answer (score 35):

There is also a builtin function in Google Spreadsheet for this. That is [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)

Using `SUMIF` the solution would be like this:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B6,"Yes",A1:A6)
```

Comment: The same goes for this that goes for [xylar's answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/43779/113046): the commas may need to be replaced with semicolons depending on language settings.

Comment: Most perfect solution