# Force cell to zero if result is below zero or N/A

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I currently have the exact function set up here: [Summing a column, filtered based on another column in Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43778/summing-a-column-based-on-another-column-in-google-spreadsheet)

The number I'm getting from the query is almost always negative (a list of transactions) so if it's more than zero, I want it to default to zero.

This is what I currently have and it's returning the zero as I'd like but not if the result of the query is #N/A

```
=MIN( SUM(FILTER( TRANSACTIONS! C4:C51; TRANSACTIONS! D4:D51="Other")) , 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question. IFERROR is what I needed to use.

```
=IFERROR(MIN(SUM(FILTER(TRANSACTIONS! C4:C51; TRANSACTIONS! D4:D51="Other"))) ,0)
```

Comment: Way to go Jeremy !!

Answer (score 1):

I always use the `ISNA()` function. As a first step, I create the **range** with `filter()`:

```
=FILTER( TRANSACTIONS! C4:C51; TRANSACTIONS! D4:D51="Other");
```

As a second step, I always use the:

```
=IF(ISNA(range);0;thingsToDoWith(range));
```

So, in your case it will become:

```
=IF(ISNA(FILTER( TRANSACTIONS! C4:C51; TRANSACTIONS! D4:D51="Other"));0;SUM(FILTER( TRANSACTIONS! C4:C51; TRANSACTIONS! D4:D51="Other")));
```

It’s pretty handy, if you get used to it.